# 10 Gwei contract creation is stuck

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment

I need help, I want to add more gas to my token/contract creation, but there is no Nonce since it's pending, how can I get this contract live/mined via Remix Ethereum IDE?

With average gas, does $90 seem correct for token creation? I basically cheaped out trying to make it $10.

`Time Last Seen:
02 days 12 hr 32 min 16 secs ago (Jan-03-2021 05:54:47 AM)

Estimated Confirmation Duration:
This txn has been pending > 24hrs (Learn more about Canceling/Replacing Txns or see our Gas Tracker)

Max Txn Cost/Fee:
0**.**00947995 Ether ($10.18)

Gas Price:
0**.**00000001 Ether (10 Gwei)

Ether Price:
$978.69 / ETH

Gas Limit:
947995
Gas Used by Transaction:
Pending
Nonce Position
0 Pending`

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you didn't provide high enough of a gas price miners don't mine the transactions. So you can either wait or replace the transaction. (I don't know how replacing a transaction works in Remix).

If you want to wait it may take days, months or forever. Or at some point the transaction may simply disappear when nodes' mempools get full and they delete "unneeded" transactions.

Comment: I believe you need the nonce number to replace by adding more gas, but it seems like the Nonce is pending

Comment: nonce is never pending, a transaction may be pending. Every transactions includes a nonce and you can "replace" a pending transaction by issuing a new transaction with the same nonce but higher gas price.